# using diff in mutate pipeline error due to first value

Tags: r

I am trying to do this:

```
df <- data.frame(y = seq(1, 100, 1)) %>%
    mutate(
        test = 100 * diff(log(y))
    )
```

and get:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `test`.
x Input `test` can't be recycled to size 100.
i Input `test` is `diff(y)`.
i Input `test` must be size 100 or 1, not 99.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I guess it has to do with the fact that there is no prior value for the first value. What is a pragmatic way to deal with this (happy with the first test value to be NA)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want `lag` where the default for the first entry is `NA`

```
df <- data.frame(y = seq(1, 100, 1)) %>%
  mutate(
    test1 = 100 * (log(y) - lag(log(y)))
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because test has a different length than y. If you add `F` at the beginning of test, everything works.

```
df <- data.frame(y = seq(1, 100, 1)) %>%
  mutate(
    test = c(F,100 * diff(log(y)))
  )
```

**EDIT**

`diff` takes a vector and builds the differences between element at position `i` with `i+1`. From a vector of length `n` you can build `n-1` differences.

```
diff(1:10)
#> [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

`diff` can use `lag` (default = 1)

```
diff(1:10, lag = 2)
#> [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

The `diff` inside your `mutate` will have one element less than the length of the DF. You will get an error message which says exactly this.
Therefor adding one element will bring the new variable to the same length.

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting is this kind of like a try catch? Thanks.

Comment: @cs0815 I have made a new edit to the post.